# MAE greater than MSE - is it possible?

Tags: machine-learning, python

I have used KNN for predicting the output power of solar panels. I have done feature scaling based on normalization for all data points. The problem is that the MAE is equal to 0.08, and MSE is equal to 0.06. I know that MSE must be greater than MAE.
What is the reason behind that ?

Comment: What does MAE stand for?  Can you spell out the acronyms?  Why do you think that MSE must be greater than MAE?

Comment: MAE stands for Mean Absolute Error and MSE stands for Mean Square Error. I think MSE must be greater than MAE because MSE is the average of squared errors while MAE is the average of absolute errors.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not correct that MSE must be greater than MAE, particularly when the errors are small.  For instance, if all errors are 0.01, then MAE will be 0.01, and MSE will be 0.0001.  See also https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/375925/2921, https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/307553/2921.